# Get Notified of Silverlight Binding Errors?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

So, lets say I write a binding in Silverlight that cannot be resolved.

I get a message in the output window:

```
"System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: ...."
```

Is there a way to get notified when this happens?  Ultimately, I'd like to throw an exception or something.  Is this somehow configurable?

Comment: Gotta a feeling this one has be been asked before

Comment: The link for AnthonyWJones's answer should be
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693378/how-does-one-detect-setbinding-sucess-or-failure-in-silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693378/how-does-one-detect-setbinding-sucess-or-failure-in-silverlight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Justin's answer to this question:-

[how does one detect setbinding sucess or failure in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693378/how-does-one-detect-setbinding-sucess-or-failure-in-silverlight)